# How can I install the libwebsocket library in Ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu, installation, libwebsockets

I am trying to install the libwebsocket in my ubuntu .

so I downloaded the project https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets
unzipped it and I followed the installation instruction.

I type the command  cmake FH  and get the following messages.

```
  You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:Locality Name (eg, city) []:Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:Email Address []:SUCCSESFULLY generated SSL certificate
Generating API documentation
-- Looking for RPMTools... - rpmbuild NOT FOUND
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  Settings:  (For more help do cmake -LH <srcpath>
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 LWS_WITH_SSL = ON  (SSL Support)
 LWS_SSL_CLIENT_USE_OS_CA_CERTS = 1
 LWS_USE_CYASSL = OFF (CyaSSL replacement for OpenSSL)
 LWS_WITHOUT_BUILTIN_GETIFADDRS = OFF
 LWS_WITHOUT_CLIENT = OFF
 LWS_WITHOUT_SERVER = OFF
 LWS_LINK_TESTAPPS_DYNAMIC = OFF
 LWS_WITHOUT_TESTAPPS = OFF
 LWS_WITHOUT_TEST_SERVER = OFF
 LWS_WITHOUT_TEST_SERVER_EXTPOLL = OFF
 LWS_WITHOUT_TEST_PING = OFF
 LWS_WITHOUT_TEST_CLIENT = OFF
 LWS_WITHOUT_TEST_FRAGGLE = OFF
 LWS_WITHOUT_DEBUG = OFF
 LWS_WITHOUT_EXTENSIONS = OFF
 LWS_WITH_LATENCY = OFF
 LWS_WITHOUT_DAEMONIZE = OFF
 LWS_USE_LIBEV = 
 LWS_IPV6 = OFF
 LWS_WITH_HTTP2 = OFF
---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/maroua/libwebsocket/libwebsockets-master
-- Cache values
// Choose the type of build, options are: None(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or CMAKE_C_FLAGS used) Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel.
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=

// Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories.
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local

// Libwebsockets include directories
LIBWEBSOCKETS_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=/home/maroua/libwebsocket/libwebsockets-master/lib;/home/maroua/libwebsocket/libwebsockets-master

// Libwebsocket libraries
LIBWEBSOCKETS_LIBRARIES:STRING=websocket;websockets_shared

// Libwebsocket shared library
LIBWEBSOCKETS_LIBRARIES_SHARED:STRING=websockets_shared

// Libwebsocket static library
LIBWEBSOCKETS_LIBRARIES_STATIC:STRING=websocket

// Path to the CyaSSL include directory
LWS_CYASSL_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=

// Path to the CyaSSL library
LWS_CYASSL_LIB:PATH=

// Installation directory for executables
LWS_INSTALL_BIN_DIR:PATH=bin

// Installation directory for CMake files
LWS_INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR:PATH=lib/cmake/libwebsockets

// Installation directory for example files
LWS_INSTALL_EXAMPLES_DIR:PATH=bin

// Installation directory for header files
LWS_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=include

// Installation directory for libraries
LWS_INSTALL_LIB_DIR:PATH=lib

// Compile with support for ipv6
LWS_IPV6:BOOL=OFF

// Link the test apps to the shared version of the library. Default is to link statically
LWS_LINK_TESTAPPS_DYNAMIC:BOOL=OFF

// Server SSL certificate directory
LWS_OPENSSL_CLIENT_CERTS:PATH=../share

// SSL support should make use of OS installed CA root certs
LWS_SSL_CLIENT_USE_OS_CA_CERTS:BOOL=ON

// Use CyaSSL replacement for OpenSSL. When settings this, you also need to specify LWS_CYASSL_LIB and LWS_CYASSL_INCLUDE_DIRS
LWS_USE_CYASSL:BOOL=OFF

// Search the system for ZLib instead of using the included one (on Windows)
LWS_USE_EXTERNAL_ZLIB:BOOL=OFF

// Don't use BSD getifaddrs implementation from libwebsockets if it is missing (this will result in a compilation error) ... Default is your libc provides it. On some systems such as uclibc it doesn't exist.
LWS_WITHOUT_BUILTIN_GETIFADDRS:BOOL=OFF

// Don't build the client part of the library
LWS_WITHOUT_CLIENT:BOOL=OFF

// Don't build the daemonization api
LWS_WITHOUT_DAEMONIZE:BOOL=OFF

// Don't compile debug related code
LWS_WITHOUT_DEBUG:BOOL=OFF

// Don't compile with extensions
LWS_WITHOUT_EXTENSIONS:BOOL=OFF

// Don't build the server part of the library
LWS_WITHOUT_SERVER:BOOL=OFF

// Don't build the libwebsocket-test-apps
LWS_WITHOUT_TESTAPPS:BOOL=OFF

// Don't build the client test application
LWS_WITHOUT_TEST_CLIENT:BOOL=OFF

// Don't build the ping test application
LWS_WITHOUT_TEST_FRAGGLE:BOOL=OFF

// Don't build the ping test application
LWS_WITHOUT_TEST_PING:BOOL=OFF

// Don't build the test server
LWS_WITHOUT_TEST_SERVER:BOOL=OFF

// Don't build the test server version that uses external poll
LWS_WITHOUT_TEST_SERVER_EXTPOLL:BOOL=OFF

// Compile with support for http2
LWS_WITH_HTTP2:BOOL=OFF

// Build latency measuring code into the library
LWS_WITH_LATENCY:BOOL=OFF

// Compile with support for libev
LWS_WITH_LIBEV:BOOL=OFF

// Include SSL support (default OpenSSL, CyaSSL if LWS_USE_CYASSL is set)
LWS_WITH_SSL:BOOL=ON

// The RPM builder tool
RPMTools_RPMBUILD_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=RPMTools_RPMBUILD_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND
```

I tried to compile a C program that uses libwebsocket.h, it tells me that it does not exist.
Can any one show me the right way to install this lib.
Thanks for any help .

Comment: Tired of these trolls -1 without trying to help. This is a legit question which got a helpful answer. Please +1 for legit questions

Comment: @joël
It may be due to the fact that libwebsockets has a build.readme which is rather detailed. But I agree that that should be stated in the comment if doing -1 because of that reason. (https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/blob/master/README.build.md)

Answer (score 45):

A simple way to install libwebsocket in Ubuntu is to use this command in a terminal:

> sudo apt-get install libwebsockets-dev

This command will install the version *1.2*.
The `libwebsockets.h` file will be located at `/usr/include/libwebsockets.h`

---

An other way to have this library is to get the latest version (*1.4* at the moment) from GitHub. To do that open a **Terminal** and go in the directory you want to get the library (I will call it `lib_dir`).

When you are in the `lib_dir` directory enter this command to get the code:

> git clone https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets.git

When the command finish you will find a directory named **libwebsockets**.
The `libwebsockets.h` file will be located at `lib_dir/libwebsockets/lib`

If you need / want to build the library and install it in your system go in `lib_dir` then enter the following commands:

> sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
>   mkdir build
>   cd build
>   cmake ..
>   make
>   sudo make install
>   ldconfig

This will install the library in `/usr/local/include`.
And to make sure of the version you just installed:

> pkg-config --modversion libwebsockets

Finally you need to include in the compiler (include paths -I):

> /usr/local/include

In the linker libraries (Libraries -l):

> websockets

Finally (Library search path -L):

> /usr/local/lib

Comment: Worked perfectly :) one question: What is libssl-dev for? Ubuntu 15.04 is shipped with this preinstalled, so no problem there, I'm just curious!

Comment: @NicolaiAntonLynnerup Glad it helped you :) It is a package that is part of the openssl project's implementation of the ssl and tls cryptographic protocols for secure communication over the internet.

Comment: Can someone explain the last three steps? (linux noob)

Comment: @KenVernaillen The last three steps are used as arguments when compiling your code. Go check [GCC and make](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html). It explain how compilation is done and how argument are set.